# connection in postgresql locally in flutter

Tags: postgresql, flutter

I try to connect locally to postgresql with flutter, the code works normally when launching it in the emulator but not from then the mobile.

```
 Future<void> getProduct() async {
    String barcode="106666";
    print("#####OKOKOKOK2");
    connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
        "192.168.1.3", 5432, "postgres", username: "username",
        password: "password");
    await connection.open();
    List<List<dynamic>> results = await connection.query(
        "SELECT P.name AS product_name,S.ppa,S.id "
            "FROM gestiondb_schema.stock S "
            "LEFT JOIN gestiondb_schema.products P ON P.id = S.product_id "
            "WHERE S.codebarre = @barcode ", substitutionValues: {
      "barcode": barcode
    });
    for (final row in results) {
      product_name.add(row[0].toString());
      product_ppa.add(row[1].toString());
    }
    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = "barcodeScanRes";
    });
  }
```

pg_hph.conf:

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5`

error in mobile :

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: TimeoutException after 0:00:30.000000: Future not completed`

Any advice?

Comment: It's not a good practice directly connect app to database. I suggest you to use a middleware server. Flutter app call the server API and in the server API you can work on the database.

Comment: it is a local wifi application